# Why upon reloading the page I am unable to go to the initial URL?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router-dom for routing. When I start the application using `npm start` then my application opens with URL as`http://localhost:3000/` then by clicking a link I route to `http://localhost:3000/buyer`( Till here everything works according to my intention ). Now when I try to reload the page the URL does not set to `http://localhost:3000/` rather it remains as `http://localhost:3000/buyer`.

I am unable to understand why upon reloading the page my URL is not set to the initial URL i.e `http://localhost:3000/`

Please someone guide me on how I could fix it.

Comment: What are you doing to reload the page? A refresh of the browser? or location.reload?

Comment: Clicking on the "Reload this page" icon on my chrome browser @Stoobish

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the link to buyer (`<Link to="/buyer">Buyer</Link>`), the router renders the matching `<Route>`. When you reload the page, its still rendering the same matching route `/buyer`.